# Alternative to Session Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, caching, console-application

I am trying to find an alternative to using a session variable. In my solution I have a project that is referenced by an ASP.NET web application and a console application. Both these applications can make changes to data and when a change is made the ID of the user making the change is logged against that row.

So if it was just the ASP.NET app making changes, it could do something like `myObj.LastUpdatedByID = Session["userid"]`. Given that the command line app needs to make changes and doesn't have a session, what alternative could I use that has the equivalent of session scope in ASP.NET but is also available in the console app scope?

I've had a look at MemoryCache, but that seems to be application level in ASP.NET.

I don't want to go down the line of passing the user ID through to each call.

Would doing something like checking for a HttpContext and if there is, pull from the session and if there isn't, pull from MemoryCahce? Or is there a better way of doing it?

EDIT:
The user ID is specifically set in the console app depending on what action is being carried. The console app is used for automated processes and there are numerous actions it undertakes. So for example, the sending email process would be carried out by user ID 1 and the delete old files process would be carried out by user ID 2. In *some* instances, the user ID would be set to the user ID that last made the change to that row of data.

EDIT:
Some example code (stripped for brevity). You can see I am using the MemoryCache here, which as I understand would be application wide and therefore not usable in ASP.NET app:

```
public class Base(
{
    private int auditID = -1;
    public int AuditID
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.auditID <= 0)
            {
                ObjectCache memCache = MemoryCache.Default;
                this.auditID = ((int)memCache["CurrentUserID"]);
            }
            return this.auditID;
        }
    }
}

public class MyObject : Base
{
    public int LastUpdatedByID { get; set; } = 0;

    public bool Save()
    {
        bool b = false;
        this.LastUpdatedByID = this.AuditID;
        //Call to DB here...
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is a user authenticated in the console app?

Comment: @CodeCaster I have added an edit

Comment: Show the code that updates the object. A class library shouldn't reference System.Web.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have added an example of how the update works. Agreed about the System.Web comment. This is why I'm trying to find a better way than checking for a HttpContext and using session, if not using MemoryCache

Comment: Are you already making use of IoC patterns? It seems you could have an `IIdentifyUser` interface that could be injected into classes that need to know about the user and then build simple Asp.Net and Console implementations. (Obviously, the console one wouldn't allow more than one action to be requested at a time, making it non-thread-safe, but there again, nor would your memory cache proposal. If you need thread safety in the console app, you'll almost certainly have to byte the bullet and pass parameters)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm not using IoC, but I am quite happy to if it works out. Being thread-safe isn't an issue at the moment - but it is a good point and could raise it's head in the future. If I go down the interface route, would I still not need to pass that to my Base class? At which point parameter passing and being thread-safe may as well be the option (I haven't worked with interfaces before so excuse my ignorance!).

Answer (score 0):

If the data needs to be persistent across application then you can't use `Session` or `HttpContext.Cache` since those are dependent on current `HttpContext` which you don't have in console app.

Another way, would be to store the data in some persistent data store like Database or distributed cache like `Redis Cache` / `Azure Mem Cache`

Comment: In case I have confused. I don't need to share the ID between the console app and the ASP.NET app. I need to the project which they both reference to know about the ID. Console app uses _core_. ASP.NET uses _core_. _core_ needs to know user ID. The ref'd project is a bunch of classes that compiles to a DLL.